# How Can we Create a plugin and Play Architecture in Django?

Tags: python, django, python-packaging, module-packaging

Actually, I want to create a plug and play architecture in Python Django. I have a different kind of **scrapers** and I am writing more **scrapers** too. Whenever I build a new **scraper** I have to again publish my repo in production. What I need I just want to plug that new **scraper** without actually again deploying my code. I have already used the GitHub versioning system but I am in need of a more clean way. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

What you should be doing is Generating the Setup.py File which would automatically set it up as a package thus, When the User would run the Setup.py File,

It would deploy it as a package. Second Thing is you can create a Package out of It with the tools already provided by Python to create a Package of an App in Django.

Packaging a Python Script:
https://the-hitchhikers-guide-to-packaging.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html
https://pythonhosted.org/an_example_pypi_project/setuptools.html

For Django, Follow below Steps:

1. Initilize it with a ReadMe File
2. Initilize it with a MANIFEST.in to include the text files and static files in our package
3. run `python setup.py build`
   Reference: https://www.pythoncentral.io/package-python-django-application-reusable-component/
   Now Simply Use it anywhere You Wish making it a Reusable App!

Reference for a Package Settled Up:
https://github.com/smfai200/rebound